# Tool for Viewing X.509 Certificates?

Tags: wcf, certificate, x509

Does anyone know of any good tools to view the store name, store location, or values of an X.509 Certificate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i'm supposing that you are using Windows. So here it is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529278.aspx. It's a good tool, but to do it thru API is not hard and it's a good exercise to learn the API.

Regards,

Victor

Comment: Thx VP.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  I can't believe I had not stumbled upon it in all my searches.

Answer (score 8):

[Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) is cross-platform (written in Java), requires no installation and can not only read certificates and keystores but also create, modify, import/export etc.

Comment: Hey Romulo.  I'll definitely check this tool out also.  I'm doing a bit of development with Java that will connect to these WCF Web Services - so it wouldn't hurt to have something that can be run on other system.  Thx!

Comment: As a side note: you may also consider the more powerful [**KeyStore Explorer**](http://www.keystore-explorer.org/). Portecle is essentially a fork of a _KeyTool GUI_, which was later renamed and remade as a KeyStore Explorer ([A History of KeyStore Explorer](https://waynedgrant.wordpress.com/2012/02/21/a-history-of-keystore-explorer-part-two/)). Not trying to belittle Portecle, just for your information.

Answer (score 3):

Openssl does it better and with more details:

openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text -noout

Comment: The command you gave only works for certs stored directly in the filesystem. But not for certs stored in one of the Windows Certificate Store. -- I don't think OpenSSL can do that.

Answer (score 2):

Also, don't forget there's a substantial number of tasks and information you can view/manage directly from windows using the Certificates MMC console.

For whatever reason, it's never in any menu by default, but you can just launch MMC.exe and then add the Certificate's snap-in. It's very useful for managing certificates deployed to your account's certificate store or to the machine certificate store (if you've got admin permissions).

Answer (score 0):

See [How to: Use the X.509 Certificate Management Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819944.aspx) on MSDN for instructions on how to use the Microsoft Management Console (MMC) Certificates snap-in to manage X.509 certificates.